# Data structure to store objects identified by unique 8digit hexadecimals for fast insertion and lookup

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, trie, skip-lists

I have a bunch of objects with unique 8 digit hexadecimal identifiers ex[fd4786ac] that I need to construct and look up quickly.  Deletion is not a priority.  These hexadecimal values are currently being stored as strings.

Considered a trie(or some variation of a trie), a skip list, and a some variation of a hash table.  Using a skip list over a AVL tree would be preferable since it is likely these strings will be sequential but not guaranteed and tree re-balancing would be often. How ever I'm open to other data structures if they better suit my need.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You mention a hash table, but can you explain why that isn't working out for you? All operations should be O(1).

Comment: Some questions:
1. Approx. how many objects do you need to insert into your data structure?
2. For each time you instantiate your data structure, approx. how many times do you need to lookup an item from the data structure?
3. What is the criteria for your lookup? Do you need to lookup random elements or is there some special criteria that your trying to find? For example, I want to find an item with the highest hex value in my data structure?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!  Hash table seemed to be my best option based on my research, however I am unsure on what variation to use.  I am hoping that since my identifiers are unique and fixed length I may have more options to work with. @ggorlen

Comment: @entpnerd 1) unkown at least 38 probaly no more than 500 but could be larger  2)ALOT 3)access elements based on look-up of identifier

Comment: What language are you trying to program in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good choice would be to convert your keys into 32-bit integers, and then use a hash table.

If you want to write your own just for this use case, then:

- Instead of hashing keys all the time or storing hash values, use a bijective hash function and use the hashes *instead of* the keys.
- Since your keys are very small you should probably use open addressing -- it will save space and it's a little faster.  Wikipedia will give you lots of choices for probing schemes.  I currently like robin hood hashing: https://www.sebastiansylvan.com/post/robin-hood-hashing-should-be-your-default-hash-table-implementation/

Answer (score 0):

Your 8 digit hexadecimal identifiers represent a 4byte (32bit) integer so you can use that as an index for a (quite large) array with 2^32 entries.
If the array contains pointers this would cost 64GB.

Most likely too much to keep it in RAM.

So if the number of elements is orders of magnitudes below 2^32, use a Hash-Map or a sorted ist (access O(logn) ).